Can anyone explain different types of cache in ElasticSearch
Can anyone explain different types of cache in ElasticSearch?
I need to understand which cache in Elasticsearch is best fit for question / answer based application. I need to understand how we can make sure top questions asked are displayed as soon as we login to the application.

Shard Request Cache also known as Request Cache
Node Query Cache, Filter Cache, via LRUQueryCache Lib.
fieldData
pageCache
I'm also still learning. Don't mind my answer.
